# Keep ratio height of div with background image in responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have html with li contains background-image but I want keep `li` size in responsive with the same ratio of image size:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">hello1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">hello2</a></li>
</ul>
<style>
ul li {width:49%; float:left; height:auto}
ul li:nth-child(1) {background:url(url1) no-repeat left top; background-size:100% auto;}
ul li:nth-child(2) {background:url(url2) no-repeat left top; background-size:100% auto;} 
ul li:nth-child(3) {background:url(url3) no-repeat left top; background-size:100% auto;} 
</style>
```

As you can see in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6La5wzg/), it contains full width but height is cropped.
I want width of li has the same ratio with height of image on resize. Thank you for your help.

Comment: anyone pls help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve with Javascript with these steps:

1) Define the background image dimensions (or their ratio of height / width).

```
var image_dimensions = [
  [512, 320],
  [512, 288],
  [512, 358],
];
```

2) Use CSS to set the width to 49% (actually, potentially better calc(50% - margin - padding;, but that's a different story).

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
}
```

*Note: I have also changed the display for inline-block which is more elegant than float: left and will prevent some issues with the alignment of the images.*

3) Iterate all lis.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('ul#image_list li');

for (var i = 0; i < image_dimensions.length && i < images.length; i++){
```

4) Check actual width of the image. Multiply the width x ratio (height / width) which gives the needed height.

```
var ratio = image_dimensions[i][1] / image_dimensions[i][0];
var height = images[i].offsetWidth * ratio;
```

5) Set the height for the image.

```
images[i].style.height = height + 'px';
```

Demo as a version of your jsfiddle:

```js
var image_dimensions = [
 [512, 320],
  [512, 288],
  [512, 358],
];

var images = document.querySelectorAll('ul#image_list li');

for (var i = 0; i < image_dimensions.length && i < images.length; i++){
  var ratio = image_dimensions[i][1] / image_dimensions[i][0];
  var height = images[i].offsetWidth * ratio;
  images[i].style.height = height + 'px';
}
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
}

ul li:nth-child(1) {background:url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-XlNXQh-wWx0/VEvOnrhNi-I/AAAAAAAAHfY/EMUT8ZWkjZ0//autumn-sad-heart-free-desktop-wallpaper-1920x1200.jpg") no-repeat left top;background-size: 100% auto;}
ul li:nth-child(2) {background:url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Ng8xrfA_UuY/VEvMCERa3LI/AAAAAAAAHdw/R3V7Tv5BgXg//fg.jpg") no-repeat left top; background-size:100% auto;} 
ul li:nth-child(3) {background:url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-VcuSwUBvb_Q/VEvNn6LSBBI/AAAAAAAAHfA/llfaD-qwBlU//vintage-letter-free-desktop-wallpaper-5672x3970.jpg") no-repeat left top; background-size:100% auto;}
```

```html
<ul id="image_list">
    <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">hello1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">hello2</a></li>
</ul>
```

PD: This code is only calculating this once. If you need it to be resizable as you change the size of the screen. You can do this with:

```
window.onresize = function(){
  // wrap all the previous code here too.
  // Or better, move it to a function and call it both on window.onload and window.onresize
};
```